# Prevent site navigation for a user who has not agreed to the terms

Tags: php, wordpress

Tring to prevent a logged in user from navigating the site if he has not approved the terms of use.
Terms of use is a checkbox that it's value is saved as user meta field.
I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'confirmation_of_terms');
function confirmation_of_terms(){
    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if( $current_user_id > 0 ){
        $permission = get_user_meta( $current_user_id, 'approval_of_regulations' , true );
        if( empty( $permission ) ){
            wp_redirect( 'example.com/welcome');
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If this code runs every time your site loads then it will just keep coming back here and redirecting them again and again. You need to redirect them to somewhere where they can agree the terms, which doesn't make this check beforehand

Comment: I am redirecting to a page with the checkbox, egnore the example.com

Comment: Well then you need to make sure the checkbox page doesn't run this code when it's loading

Comment: That solved the problem!! THANKS!!!